# How to query BLOB as CLOB in H2 database

Tags: sql, h2

To project BLOB into CLOB in Oracle I can do this query:

```sql
SELECT ent.ID, to_clob(ent.blob_string) from entity_1 ent;
```

However, I could not find the `to_clob` equivalent operation in H2 to see my data in H2-console. How I can do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on content of your BLOB. In H2 Console you actually can see `BLOB` and other binary values as is in hexadecimal representation without any additional functions around them.

You can use `CAST(ent.blob_string AS VARCHAR)` (or `CAST(ent.blob_string AS CLOB)`) to convert a binary string to a character string explicitly, but such conversion uses different encodings in different versions of H2. Old versions use hexadecimal representation, new versions use UTF-8. You can use `UTF8TOSTRING(ent.blob_string)` function for UTF-8 conversion in old and new versions. There is also `RAWTOHEX(ent.blob_string)` function, but its behavior is also different between different versions of H2 and its compatibility modes.